# Homepage at session restore shows relative dates from the last time you closed Firefox

Tags: bug, new-nav, firefox

I've noticed in Firefox 43 in win10 x64, the following:
*(provided that in Firefox Options you have set:

General|When Firefox starts|`Show my windows and tabs from last time`

and the `Don't load tabs until selected` is checked)*

In general, with the above settings, if you close and reopen Firefox, then your tabs are restored from last session.
Well, the issue is that in your restored SE homepage tab, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/
the relative timestamps for the questions
i.e. the `innerHTML` of the elements with classname `relativetime`, for example: `1 min ago`
**is the one from the last time you closed Firefox** (*cached*),
and therefore, every 1 min that the relevant relative timestamps increase,
(something which is done via a script, i.e. locally)
**it's increased based on the cached(=old) relative timestamps**.

---

Example:

- open a homepage: https://stackoverflow.com/
  (while you have login and you're using the new navigation)
- let's suppose that the top question title displayed was asked at `2015-12-17 19:00:00Z`
  *(that's the info displayed as tooltip while you hover your mouse on its timestamp,

  i.e. the absolute timestamp)*. Its relative timestamp is `10 sec ago`
- let 1 minute pass: the relative timestamp displayed will become `1 min ago`
- close Firefox
- re-open Firefox after 10 min: you'll notice that the relative timestamp will still be `1 min ago`, and after 1 min will become `2 min ago` and so on.

---

In Chrome 46 *(having Settings|On startup|`Continue where you've left of`)*
the issue doesn't occur.

I posted about this in [bug 706970 - Tabs restored at startup (app tabs, session restore) should be loaded bypassing cache](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=706970#c44)

Comment: Reputation also gets cached here.